# how to move from one form to another in MFC

Tags: forms, mfc

I am designing a set-up wizard using MFC application controls... how do I move from one form to another in a button click.plz help me guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of an indirect answer to your question -- its been a few years since I've done MFC.

Get your hands on a book called "MFC Internals" by Scot Wingo, George Shepherd and Dean McCrory (Amazon: http://www.amazon.ca/MFC-Internals-Microsoft-Foundation-Architecture/dp/0201407213). Its kind of old (but so is MFC), but it does have the answers.

I thought that MFC had a built-in class or set of classes for handling wizards. All you have to do is create the various pages of the wizard and the main class handles the rest.

Anyway, get the book and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

The MFC class [kmontgom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817796/how-to-move-from-one-form-to-another-in-mfc/1817844#1817844) was thinking of is [CPropertysheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3fkt014(VS.80).aspx).

> To create a wizard-type dialog box, follow the same steps you would follow to create a standard property sheet, but call SetWizardMode before you call DoModal. To enable the wizard buttons, call SetWizardButtons, using flags to customize their function and appearance. To enable the Finish button, call SetFinishText after the user has taken action on the last page of the wizard.

Comment: is there anything like a panel so that we can hide forms...what i want is to move to next form in a button click event